# Azure deployment not including dll reference

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API that's hosted in Azure, and I have continuous deployment set up from a GitHub repository.

There's some functionality I need to implement that relies on a third-party DLL, so I added it as a reference to my project. Everything works fine locally, but when I commit my changes with the new DLL, the deployment fails in Azure with this message:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyReference' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I open my .csproj file, this is how the reference is added, so maybe there's an issue there:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="MyReference">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Users\MyUser\Downloads\library-sdk-csharp\lib\MyReference.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

If I go to GitHub and look at the code, I can see my dll in /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/

I tried setting CopyLocal to True, but that didn't fix anything. Anything else I can do to fix this? This seems like a fairly simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you actually referenced this Assembly (DLL) by a relative path depending on your local environment (the User-folder part is an hint). But if you use continous deployment tirggered by a git repo all the stuff must be referenceable from the git repo or the build process. In the build environment the releative path is not available and this is why it can not be referenced.

**Solution:**
1. Reference your assembly as a nuget package and call a `nuget restore` in your continous integeration build process
- or -
2. Create a kind of `lib`folder in your project and place your third party assembly there. Than commit this library as part of your project (reference it there relative to your project)

Hope this helps...